# 1 код, 2 девайса - 2 UI

Tags: android, button, ui

Запускаю один код на двух разных девайсах, интерфейс отличается, могу предположить, что все дело в системных настройках прошивки. Как можно на девайсе №2 избавиться от таких уродских кнопок?

Девайс №1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Девайс №2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.hfad.simplefocus.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="@string/etHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:text="25:00"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartPause"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:text="@string/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:text="@string/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: добавить margin?

Comment: В таком случае на 1м девайсе будет расстояние еще больше.

Comment: разметку в студию

Comment: @m-g-demin добавил.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно принципам вам необходимо расставить расстояния между контентом, а по хорошему:

1.Нужно сделать отступы от края экрана 16dp

2.Использовать направляющие, в вашем случае подойдет основной элемент к примеру ваш TextView timer.

3.Использовать актуальные размеры кратные сетки в 8dp, те текст 25sp и 55sp - не подходит. Пример 24sp  56sp

4.Использовать 1 ViewParent, здесь его более, чем достаточно.

5.Убрать соотношения веса между layout, это может привести к неожиданным результатам, особенно когда используем wrap_content и match_parent

6.Расстояние между контентом для кнопок к примеру 4dp будет достаточно, так это внутренние элементы.

7.Дать подышать тексту внутри View выставить padding в 2dp к примеру.

Это из того, что бы я сразу сделал.

Comment: одним словом можно сказать, что нужно читать [гайдлайны](https://material.google.com/) :)

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei Направляющие?

Comment: ну да, их по разному называют в MD, но по рус, это направляющие. 
В вашем макете, это центральная вертикальная линия вдоль всего экрана, но можете использовать главный элемент и относительного него работать, как я и написал в п.2

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать вот такую разметку:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:background="@drawable/md_transparent"
    android:text=""
    android:hint="Ваш текст"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:text="25:00"
    android:textSize="55sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartPause"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:text="START"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="123"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Должно помочь с кнопками.